# Seeking inspiration for software suite dashboard

Tags: website-design, interface-design, inspiration

I am in the middle of designing a software suite's dashboard, however I am in a bit of a rut as my only source of inspiration is Adobe's Creative Cloud software suite dashboard http://www.adobe.com/creativecloud/catalog/desktop.html

Does anyone know of other software suite dashboards that I may glean some inspiration from? Or perhaps I'm using the wrong search terms as all I've been coming up with are product dashboards or just general app dashboards, not really what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Does searching "web dashboard design examples" not give you enough examples? You can change web with app if need be.

Comment: By dashboard you mean a marketing page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's a matter of UI/UX design which better represents your brand & product. Getting inspiration elsewhere is valid, but that wouldn't be better than prototyping/designing your own interface in order to showcase your software or apps.

Perhaps you're trying to describe a software/app showcase or portfolio, and if I'm right you could get inspired by some great software companies out there.

I'm personally very fond of clean & intuitive UI/UX design. The following companies do showcase their work nicely (not placing active links because of reputation limit), anyway here are they:

```
http://sourcebits.com/app-development-portfolio/

http://smallplanet.com/apps/

http://www.appsterhq.com/portfolio/

http://messapps.com/portfolio/

https://fueled.com/

https://slack.com/apps

http://pixiteapps.com/

https://www.apple.com/osx/apps/
```

Just take a look at these companies' websites. They all have very nice ways to showcase their software/apps ranging from simple to advanced concepts, all of them very "trending" UI/UX concepts though.

That should not be taken as the only way to go, because when it comes to work showcase design, the best bet is always to apply all your creativity to create a great design while building an effective user experience, in this case, the most intuitive, the better.